# Regex or statement

Tags: php, regex

I have regex:

```
preg_match( '/\/user\/([^\/?#]+)/', $url, $matches )
```

To get the username part of string:

```
https://www.youtube.com/user/username
```

So it checks what comes after `user`. How do I adjust it so it grabs the username in this example:

```
https://www.youtube.com/c/username
```

I've tried adding `|c` like this:

```
'\/user|c\/([^\/?#]+)'
```

But it doesn't work. What's the accurate approach?

Comment: `'/\/(?:user|c)\/([^\/?#]+)/'`

Comment: Thanks. I see I was nearly there. Do you wanna write up a quick answer so I can accept?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Couldn't make it work with this suggestion, see [demo](https://ideone.com/oV6UHe). What am I missing?

Comment: There is a typo, you included the regex delimiters to the variable, see https://ideone.com/UdjkT6

Comment: Ah, you're right, I'm an idiot. Please feel free to post the answer and I'll accept. Will purge the comments here after.